# Convert MySQL query to Laravel query builder code

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, query-builder

I am working with agricultural product management system. I have a question regarding a MySQL query. I would like to know how to create the same query using Laravel query builder:

```
SELECT
    vegitables.name, vegitables.image, vegitables.catagory,
    AVG(price_wholesale),
    SUM(CASE WHEN rank = 1 THEN price_wholesale ELSE 0 END) today,
    SUM(CASE WHEN rank = 2 THEN price_wholesale ELSE 0 END) yesterday
FROM (
    SELECT
        veg_id, price_wholesale, price_date,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY veg_id ORDER BY price_date DESC) as rank
    FROM old_veg_prices
) p
INNER JOIN vegitables ON p.veg_id = vegitables.id
WHERE rank in (1,2)
GROUP BY veg_id
```

This Output result get when run query in database:

[image: output result want]

Following two table are used to get today price yesterday price and price average get from each product.

[image: vegetable table]

```
CREATE TABLE `vegitables` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `catagory` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `total_area` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Total area of culativate in Sri Lanka (Ha)',
  `total_producation` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Total production particular product(mt)',
  `annual_crop_count` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'how many time can crop pre year',
  `short_dis` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `vegitables`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `vegitables`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
COMMIT;
```

[image: Old vegetable price table]

```
CREATE TABLE `old_veg_prices` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `veg_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price_wholesale` double(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `price_retial` double(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `price_location` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price_date` date NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
    ALTER TABLE `old_veg_prices`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `old_veg_prices`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
COMMIT;
```

I try [this site](https://sql2builder.github.io/) to convert to MySQL query to query builder code. But it show some error's could find it out. Any Way i want to run this code in Laravel with any method??

[image: this is error in https://sql2builder.github.io/]

Comment: Google "Laravel Raw Query"

Comment: "I've tried this site" and get an error. Post the CODE you've tried, and add the error to your question. Maybe then someone can help you

Comment: The query won't show you yesterday and today rates, but the last two rates (one row could be day before yesterday and other could be few years ago). Is that the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will not return the data for yesterday and today; it will return the data for two most recent dates (e.g. if today is 2021-11-01 and most recent two dates for for carrots are 2021-10-25 and 2021-10-20 it will use those two dates). Using `RANK() ... IN (1, 2)` is also incorrect because it can return ranks such as 1 followed by 3 instead of 2.

To get today and yesterday prices you don't need window functions. Just use appropriate where clause and conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT vegitables.name
     , vegitables.image
     , vegitables.catagory
     , AVG(old_veg_prices.price_wholesale) AS avgwholesale
     , SUM(CASE WHEN old_veg_prices.price_date = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN old_veg_prices.price_wholesale END) AS yesterday
     , SUM(CASE WHEN old_veg_prices.price_date = CURRENT_DATE THEN old_veg_prices.price_wholesale END) AS today
FROM vegitables
INNER JOIN old_veg_prices ON vegitables.id = old_veg_prices.veg_id
WHERE old_veg_prices.price_date IN (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY, CURRENT_DATE)
GROUP BY vegitables.id -- other columns from vegitables table are functionally dependent on primary key
```

The Laravel equivalent would be:

```php
DB::table('vegitables')
    ->Join('old_veg_prices', 'old_veg_prices.veg_id', '=', 'vegitables.id')
    ->whereRaw('old_veg_prices.price_date IN (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY, CURRENT_DATE)')
    ->select(
        'vegitables.name',
        'vegitables.image',
        'vegitables.catagory',
        DB::raw('AVG(old_veg_prices.price_wholesale) AS avgwholesale'),
        DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN old_veg_prices.price_date = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN old_veg_prices.price_wholesale END) AS yesterday'),
        DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN old_veg_prices.price_date = CURRENT_DATE THEN old_veg_prices.price_wholesale END) AS today')
    )
    ->groupBy(
        'vegitables.id',
        'vegitables.name',
        'vegitables.image',
        'vegitables.catagory'
    )
    ->get();
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'slagro.vegitables.name' isn't in GROUP BY

Comment: above error happen when run the query

Comment: Add `vegitables.name, vegitables.image, vegitables.catagory` to the group by. But it should not have been a problem on MySQl 5.7 or MySQL 8 if `vegitables.id` defined as primary key.

Comment: thank you very much your valuable contribution

Answer (score 1):

"Query builder" features of abstraction products often leave out some possible SQL constructs.  I recommend you abandon the goal of reverse engineering SQL back to Laravel and simply perform the "raw" query.

Also...

```
rank() OVER (PARTITION BY veg_id ORDER BY price_date DESC) as rank
```

requires MySQL 8.0 (MariaDB 10.2).

And suggest you avoid the alias "rank" since that is identical to the name of a function.

Comment: i try raw query method also but it also getting error

Comment: Please show us the complete error message.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

Comment: DB::select('myquery')->get();

Comment: i used laravel 8 latest version i thin mysql version not a problem

Comment: That `GROUP` message is pointing out that there are 2 prices for veg_id 1; hence the query is ambiguous and needs clarification.  Cf `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table -- preferably in text, not image.

Comment: okay i will update code both table

Comment: i update both create table statement

Comment: @NipunSachinda - No indexes, not even a `PRIMARY KEY`??

Comment: Is the avg price supposed to be over all time, or just over today and yesterday?  (I think it is computing the latter.)

Comment: average mean overall time price average in each product

Comment: some time one date have more than one update in particular product ,in case i need to get last updated price

Comment: primary key date in both table updated in question